# How to properly scale div with text on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to click on a `<div>` (with some text in it) and be able to scale it properly. I scale the `<div>` using `transform: scale(<x>)`.

The problem with the below code is that the scaling pushes the `<div>` "forward" and sort of spazzes out on hovering. I effect I would like is that it pops-out, such that, it stays in the middle, but, it expands its width and height.

Example (notice the font size increases):

[image]

Sample code with the problem:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>This is a div.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translate should also be adjusted for the scaled version:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:hover {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div>This is a div.</div>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, this works! I would like to know how you would know how much to translate back by?

Comment: @user12055579 no, you should translate THEN scale and keep your original translation (check the duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif So you just translate it back to the original? i.e. `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5)`?

Comment: @user12055579 yes

Comment: updated per @TemaniAfif's suggestion.